# Read File from Classpath when Server is stopped

Tags: java, classloader

I am reading hiberante.cfg.xml from Classpath. It works fine when Server is up and running. But fails if I try to access it from a standalone class.
I understand that I can change file access code to `getClass().getClassLoader().getResources()`. As its a connectionFactory class and I want to use something which can work when server is up or stopped.

Comment: How can code run on the server if it's stopped?

Comment: I am writing a test class to get the db connection. Rest of the code doesn't depend on session or httprequest.

Comment: You call some jar to get the file on server? Why did you put this file as external file (static resource on disk) on project? 
This will allow you to acess the file without depend on your server.

Comment: Example: Put your hiberante.cfg.xml on folder: home/app/projectname/config/hiberante.cfg.xml and read from this path.

Comment: What does "fails" means? Is there an exception? If so, what is it? And what's the *complete* stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried writing a Junit and setting up the application context.
What error are you getting "resource not found"?

When you use **.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName)** it considers the location of the fileName is at the root